# Flutter - Container with ring progress indicator border

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve a container that will have a progress indicator border, like in this image:

[image]

I've tried to achieve it using a container inside another container (1 container for the outside white border, and one container for the inside blue background with the icon), but I can't achieve the progress indicator effect.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Try with `CustomPainter`.

Comment: are you going to need to use some custom value for the progress? or a simple progress animation should work?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh What do you mean?

Comment: @pedropimont I am willing to give it a value from 0 to 100 that will represent the progress (0 is no border at all and 100 is full border)

Comment: I think it will easy to make with [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) you need the output right?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh How can I do that?

Comment: passing a value parameter on painter what will be responsible to show progress, l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a `CustomPainter` you can try to achieve that with a `Stack` widget

You can see this example in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id)

Use the `value` property on the second `CircularProgressIndicator` to update the value with `setState` or any other *State Management* technique you like

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: const [
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          radius: 24,
          child: Icon(Icons.check),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.grey,
            value: 1,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.blue,
            value: .3, // Change this value to update the progress
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks great. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a widget called CircularProgressIndicator that seems to be exactly what you're after.

**How to use it:**

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
              color: Colors.purple.withAlpha(100), 
              strokeWidth: 5,
              value: value, //
            ),
```

`backgroundColor`: for the white background

`color`: for the purple overlay

`strokeWidth`: for the thickness that you want

`value`: the actual progress of the indicator

And to have the arrow on top just use a round white Container (use a `BoxDecoration` with `shape: BoxShape.circle` to make it a circle), and put the arrow on top of it using the `Stack` widget.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class ProgressPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double value;
  double deg2rad(double deg) => deg * pi / 180;
  ProgressPainter({
    required this.value,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blueGrey;

    final rect = Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset(size.height / 2, size.width / 2),
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height);

    canvas.drawArc(
        rect,
        deg2rad(-90),
        deg2rad(
          (value * 360) / 100, // % to degree
        ),
        true,
        paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And use

```dart
      CustomPaint(
                  painter: ProgressPainter(value: sliderVal),
                  child: const SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Icon( // your inner widget
                      Icons.ac_unit,
                      size: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Tested widget:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double sliderVal = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomPaint(
              painter: ProgressPainter(value: sliderVal),
              child: const SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.ac_unit,
                  size: 100,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Slider(
              value: sliderVal,
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  sliderVal = value;
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```